# Outline/Edge detection of UIImage in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to extract  the  outline of UIImage for one of my application . The requirement is that ,i want to process the actual uiimage and extract the outline for painting as mentioned in the below picture. I found a solution that, we can implement this with imagemagick apis.
I am not sure whether any API is available in Iphone SDK for doing this.If not how can i implement this using imagemagick apis,(communication between C language in imagemagick and Objective C)

Thanks in advance...

[image]

Comment: you found any solution?